# Array Separated and stored into one array

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13.75
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7.15
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 38
        )

)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13.75
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8.25
            [1] => 26
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 38
        )
```

I have two array with multiple elements i need to all value in one array with comma seperated like this:
Array

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13.75,
            [1] => 26,
            [2] => 18,
            [3] => 38
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7.15,
            [1] => 26,
            [2] => 18,
            [3] => 38
        ),



    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13.75,
            [1] => 26,
            [2] => 18,
            [3] => 38
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8.25,
            [1] => 26,
            [2] => 18,
            [3] => 38
        )

)
```

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function.

Comment: i have multiple array like this array ( [0]==> with some elements ,[1]==> with some elements, [2]==> with some elements ) with another array array ( [0]==> with some elements ,[1]==> with some elements) I WANT ALL ELEMENTS into one array.

Answer (score 1):

You can used [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function to merge two array.

See below code

```
$arr1 = array(array(13.75,26,18,38),array(7.15,26,18,38)); // <- your first array
$arr2 = array(array(13.75,26,18,38),array(8.25,26,18,38)); // <- your second array

$myarr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($myarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

@vivek manavadariya simply use foreach() like below:

```
    <?php
        $arr1 = array(
                    array(
                            0 => 13.75,
                            1 => 26,
                            2 => 18,
                            3 => 38
                        ),

                    array(
                            0 => 7.15,
                            1 => 26,
                            2 => 18,
                            3 => 38
                        )

            );

    $arr2 = array(
                array(
                        0 => 13.75,
                        1 => 26,
                        2 => 18,
                        3 => 38
                    ),
                array(
                        0 => 8.25,
                        1 => 26,
                        2 => 18,
                        3 => 38
                    )
            );
    $finalArr = array();
    foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
        $finalArr[] = $value;
    }
    foreach ($arr2 as $value) {
        $finalArr[] = $value;
    }


    // or with array_merge()


   $finalArr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($finalArr);
```